# автоматизация запросов к веб-интерфейсу (RestAPI) Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, rest

Есть необходимость выгружать JSON-файл с данными за определенный промежуток времени из веб-интерфейса через RestAPI. Лимит записей в полученном файле - 100. В самом файле информация о действиях и временем, когда это действие произошло. Если за запрашиваемый промежуток времени данных больше, чем на 100 записей, полученный ответ об этом сигнализирует - moreDataAvailable = True. Чтобы получить недостающие данные, необходимо сформировать новый request и в url прописать время последнего полученного события (receivedDateTime) вместо starttime и прибавить к нему 1 милисекунду.

На Python'е удалось сделать запрос к Веб-интерфейсу через requests.get()

```
 >>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get(
...     'https://api.blablabla.com/event/eventstatuses?requestId=1234&datetype=received&starttime=2020-02-10T00%3A00%3A57.001Z&...'
... )
>>> json_response = response.json()
>>> print(json_response)
```

Как возможно автоматизировать запросы для выгрузки всех необходимых данных за запрашиваемый период? (moreDataAvailable = False)
Можно ли полученные JSONы объединить в один?

Comment: Использовать цикл `while`, пока `moreDataAvailable` истинно, в теле цикла делать запросы, накапливать ответы и проводить все необходимые манипуляции со `starttime`. Так бы подошло?

Comment: Думал об этом, но в данном случае у меня starttime находится в URL. Соответственно, при каждом новом запросе этот параметр в URL должен меняться. Поэтому и возникает вопрос, как заставить его там меняться...

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял...

Зависит, конечно, откуда берется этот URL, откуда берутся параметры для него. Его же можно формировать из нескольких переменных.

Так как у меня нет доступа к интерфейсу, то я написал просто распечатывание URL, но оставил в комментариях, чем это заменить.

Возможно, функция `isoformat()` не подойдет, ну вдруг. Тогда пригодится [strftime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). Другими словами, я сделал кучу разумных предположений о формате ответа и код придется приспособить под свою ситуацию. Своей задачей увидел только показать, как формировать URL динамически.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import requests


def form_url(request_id, datetype, starttime):
    url_pattern = 'https://api.blablabla.com/event/eventstatuses?requestId={}&datetype={}&starttime={}&...'  # дополняем тем, что есть по факту в параметрах
    return url_pattern.format(request_id, datetype, starttime.isoformat())


events = []  # здесь будет список событий
starttime = datetime(2020, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0)
moreDataAvailable = True
for i in range(5):  # меняем на: while moreDataAvailable:
    url = form_url('1234',  'received', starttime)
    print(url)  # меняем на: response = requests.get(url)
    # response_json = response.json()
    # обновляем условие остановки: moreDataAvailable = response_json['moreDataAvailable']
    # добавляем агрегацию ответов, если в ответе список, то так: events += response_json['events']
    starttime += timedelta(milliseconds=1)  # меняем на: starttime = response_json['events'][-1]['starttime'] + timedelta(milliseconds=1)
```

Вывод программы такой:

```
https://api.blablabla.com/event/eventstatuses?requestId=1234&datetype=received&starttime=2020-02-10T00:00:00&...
https://api.blablabla.com/event/eventstatuses?requestId=1234&datetype=received&starttime=2020-02-10T00:00:00.001000&...
https://api.blablabla.com/event/eventstatuses?requestId=1234&datetype=received&starttime=2020-02-10T00:00:00.002000&...
https://api.blablabla.com/event/eventstatuses?requestId=1234&datetype=received&starttime=2020-02-10T00:00:00.003000&...
https://api.blablabla.com/event/eventstatuses?requestId=1234&datetype=received&starttime=2020-02-10T00:00:00.004000&...
```

Т.е. мы много раз по одной миллисекунде прибавляем и получаем URL для запроса новой порции, а когда moreDataAvailable станет ложно - цикл остановится.

Ну и выскажусь по поводу архитектурного решения API. Критика заключается в способе постраничного доступа. Гораздо проще было бы заиметь параметры `pageSize` и `pageNumber`, но если это какое-то совершенно сторонне API и они решили, что их клиентам так комфортно, либо им так комфортно реализовать свою логику, ну чтож...

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ. Моя вина - не уточнил важную деталь: время последнего полученного события - receivedDateTime. Это время, увеличенное на 1 милисекунду, необходимо вставлять в url последующих запросов.

Comment: KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-3f4fb23af07c> in <module>
      6         response_json = response.json()
      7         moreDataAvailable = response_json['moreDataAvailable']
----> 8         events += response_json[events']
      9         starttime = response_json['events'][-1]['receivedDateTime']+timedelta(milliseconds=1)

KeyError: 'events'

Comment: Я не смог угадать, какого формата json вашего ответа. Под `response_json['events']` я подразумевал то место, где эти события хранятся. Это же должен быть какой-то список?

Comment: Да, это список: событие (срабатывание триггера) - createddatetime (время события) - receiveddatetime (время, когда данные о событии получены БД) - участник - различные данные, исходя из contentfilter в URL.

Comment: Небольшое дополнение, что может пригодиться функция `strptime()` у типа `datatime`, 100% дата и время события придет в строковом формате и ее надо будет парсить в объект типа `datetime`. Повторюсь, что я привел подход к написанию кода, а не готовую программу. Ну и здесь этим не занимаются. Вполне нормально, что после разрешения одних трудностей возникают другие. Тогда лучше оформить новый вопрос. А если мой ответ не вполне решает изначальную проблему - отредактировать текущий вопрос и включить в него недостающие детали. В комментариях их выразить довольно проблематично.